# Getting features by attribute using PyQgis?

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

How can I get a feature's geometry from selection by attribute?

For instance from a point layer I want to get the geometry by the field CODICE filter (CODICE = A001).

I tried with:

```
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("My_layer")[0]
selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression("\"CODICE\" = 'A001'")))
geom = selection.geometry()
```

It doesn't work, and the python console error is:

> AttributeError: 'QgsFeatureIterator' object has no attribute 'geometry'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is correct and working. However, the result you get back from `layer.getFeatures` is a `QgsFeatureIterator` and not a `QgsFeature`. You have potentially more than 1 feature in `selection`. You can simply iterate over your selection to get all the features:

```
for feature in selection:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    # do something with geom
```

Comment: Just a last question: if I'm sure that the result from the `layer.getFeatures` is only one feature, then is it correct to use the sintax: `selection.next()`, intead of the iteration?

Comment: More generally, it is a Python [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) look at [Python list iterator behavior and next(iterator)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16815056)

Comment: Dear @chkaiser, dear all, 
thanks for your answer. The feature geometry selection works, but unfortunately I have another problem. In some cases there is not the feature with requested "CODICE", and this is because I have to match two different layers to understand when they have the same code. 
When the two layers don't have the same code the `getFeature` gives me an error and the program stops. In this case I would like to skip to request to start another one. Do you have some suggestions? Really thanks.